# how to go next field in tabular oracle form?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm creating 2 tabular form and move one field to 2nd tabular form field. Look image below

[image]

**CODE:**

```
 BEGIN

 :EMP1.EMPNO := :EMP.EMPNO;
 :EMP.EMPNO := NULL;

 :EMP1.ENAME := :EMP.ENAME;
 :EMP.ENAME := NULL;

 :EMP1.JOB := :EMP.JOB;
 :EMP.JOB := NULL;

:EMP1.MGR := :EMP.MGR;
:EMP.MGR := NULL;

:EMP1.HIREDATE := :EMP.HIREDATE;
:EMP.HIREDATE := NULL;

:EMP1.SAL := :EMP.SAL;
:EMP.SAL := NULL;

:EMP1.COMM := :EMP.COMM;
:EMP.COMM := NULL;

:EMP1.DEPTNO := :EMP.DEPTNO;
:EMP.DEPTNO := NULL;

END;
```

When move button press then successfully moved to next tabular filed but cursor goes to 1st field and give error field must be entered. I want cursor goes to second field and when button press then move to next tabular second filed. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting all EMP block's items to `NULL`, simply `DELETE_RECORD`. So:

```
BEGIN
  :EMP1.EMPNO    := :EMP.EMPNO;
  :EMP1.ENAME    := :EMP.ENAME;
  :EMP1.JOB      := :EMP.JOB;
  :EMP1.MGR      := :EMP.MGR;
  :EMP1.HIREDATE := :EMP.HIREDATE;
  :EMP1.SAL      := :EMP.SAL;
  :EMP1.COMM     := :EMP.COMM;
  :EMP1.DEPTNO   := :EMP.DEPTNO;

  DELETE_RECORD;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no reason except that your first field( `:EMP.EMPNO` ) has `Required` property set to `Yes` in the `Data` part of the `Property Palette`, and you're trying to set it to `NULL`[ as `:EMP.EMPNO := NULL;` ] .

- Change it to `No`.

I think because `EMPNO` is a primary key column of `EMP`  table, and *Forms* presumes that field as a `Required` one.

> *P.S. If you want to commit changes you have made, Changing Required property of `:EMP.EMPNO` to `No` wouldn't be enough, since it's a
>   primary key. So as you're setting that to null, the DML `delete emp where empno = :EMP.EMPNO;` [ of course `insert into emp1(empno,...) values(:EMP.EMPNO,....)` ] should be issued during your deletion time assuming `EMP1` as a seperate table )  should be issued inside your above
>   code.*